# How to bind the json value element to the array in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

For example:

```
this.tenants = [];

this.list = [
    {id: "123", displayname: "john"}, 
    {id: "456", displayname: "victor"}, 
    {id: "789", displayname: "adam"}
];

this.tenants = this.list;
```

Comment: Please don't revert when someone formats the messy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `slice` method :

```
this.tenants = this.list.slice();
```

Comment: slice method is not working. i think there will change in declaration of tenants.

Comment: No errors but not binded with  this.tenants

Is there any other way to bind??

Comment: it's working see here : https://plnkr.co/edit/SUHXhNYCQmgiaBSPLCMf?p=info , are you doing something else in your code ?

Comment: I have tried with declaraing as tenants:Array<Object> = [];                                                  but i got error as Property 'id' does not exist with type object

Comment: in the plunker link , there is a working code try to test it , i used your code then i added this `this.tenants = this.list.slice();` , it works perfectly